# Excel vba Runtime Error 91 Object Variable or With block not set

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the below code to get data from website. Everything is ok but when result received in sheets (L column) then got an error 91 with yellow mark (code break). But when again press F5 then got result in specific column again its stop same place.

```
Sub Pull_Data()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim Link As Object


Dim i As Long
Dim output As Integer
Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

output = 212

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = wkb.ActiveSheet

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = False

  
        IE.navigate "http://119.40.95.162:8991/Pages/User/ConsumerInfo.aspx"
       
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        DoEvents
        Loop
           
      For i = 212 To ws.Range("A55000").End(xlUp).Row
     
        Set doc = IE.document
       
        doc.getElementById("cphMain_txtConsumer").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("H-3").Range("D" & i).Value
       
        doc.getElementById("cphMain_btnReport").Click
       
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        DoEvents
        Loop

  With ws

        .Range("L" & i).Value = doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText
        .Range("M" & i).Value = doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(5).innerText
        .Range("N" & i).Value = doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(12).innerText
        .Range("O" & i).Value = doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(11).innerText
  End With
             
        Set doc = IE.document
        Set ElementCol = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        
       
        For Each Link In ElementCol
            If Link.innerHTML = "Search Again " Then
                Link.Click
            End If
        Next Link
       
       Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        DoEvents
        Loop
       
    Next i


Set IE = Nothing


IE.Quit

NoItems:

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is being highlighted / where is the error being raised, specifically?

Comment: .Range("L" & i).Value = doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText

Comment: There is likely something wrong with `doc.getElementById("example3").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText`, but impossible to tell from here. Split this command into pieces and figure out which part fails (is there an ID `example3`, if yes: has this element a `tr`, if yes does this have an `item(1)` and so on)

Comment: example3, tr & item(1) is ok we got data which I want. When code is running in specific line & showing error & I click again F5 then result showing

Comment: You can try... I give u some D column data 23171213, 
23171228, 
23171232, 
23171247, 
23171251,
23171266

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I know, if there are issues which are not there by clicking F5 or F8, there is a timing problem. That's exacly what happans with your code. I will explain it, because this is a major bug in many web scraping projects with the IE.

You use the following code to wait for the page to load:

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
DoEvents
Loop
```

That works ... But only **one time**. If the status of the IE is once set to `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` it never will be resetted till the end of code. Because of that your second use of the mentioned code snippet does not work. The loop will left immediately. The page was not loaded and that's the reason for the *Runtime Error 91 Object Variable or With block not set*.  The `readyState` property is *read only*. So we can't reset it manually.

I have completely rewritten the macro. It reads all datasets from the web table to Excel. (For every row the 4 values you want.) Because of that I assume that the customer numbers are placed in another sheet (H-3) than you need the data from the webpage.

If you use `ActiveSheet` as table to import the data use an empty sheet to see what happens. The first imported row will be the first empty row in the sheet. So you can start another customer number list with the same data sheet.

I have set IE visibility to `True` so you can see how different the page access times are. You can of course set the visibility to `False` at any time. During development, I advise you to always make IE visible. This way you can see what is happening and no IE corpses accumulate in memory. For example, with the code from your question, you can see that error 91 appears before the page with the table has been loaded.

**There are many comments. Please read them carefully. I think you can learn a lot:**

```
Sub Pull_Data()

Const url As String = "http://119.40.95.162:8991/Pages/User/ConsumerInfo.aspx"

Dim ie As Object
Dim nodeDataTable As Object
Dim nodeAllDataRows As Object
Dim nodeOneDataRow As Object
Dim nodeDropdown As Object
Dim nodeDate As Object
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim numberSheet As Worksheet 'Excel sheet with the consumer numbers in column D
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet   'Excel sheet for the wanted data from the internet
Dim currRowNumberSheet As Long
Dim firstRowNumberSheet As Long
Dim lastRowNumberSheet As Long
Dim currRowDataSheet As Long
Dim timeoutStart As Double

  Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
  Set numberSheet = wkb.Sheets("H-3")
  'If you use ActiveSheet as dataSheet you MUST start the makro from from the dataSheet!!!
  'Otherwise the makro will write all data in the real ActiveSheet
  Set dataSheet = wkb.ActiveSheet
  firstRowNumberSheet = 1 '212 'Are you sure that's your first row with a number in column D?
  lastRowNumberSheet = numberSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row column D of the numberSheet
  currRowDataSheet = dataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 'Last used row of the dataSheet in general
  
  'Loop over all numbers in column D
  For currRowNumberSheet = firstRowNumberSheet To lastRowNumberSheet
    'Since the IE is a real old diva I recommend to start it new in every loop run
    'This way we have a defined state for each page call
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate url
    'The following line only works one time for an open ie
    'After the readyState is once set to complete there is no reset
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    'Place current number from the number sheet to the webpage and click submit button
    ie.document.getElementById("cphMain_txtConsumer").Value = numberSheet.Range("D" & currRowNumberSheet).Value
    ie.document.getElementById("cphMain_btnReport").Click
    
    'Here you must wait to load the page you want, but like I wrote obove, we need another way for the right break
    'Aplication.Wait() is a possibility, but it wastes time in any case because you have to set up a fixed waiting period of time
    'A much more very prettier better way is a loop
    'In those loop we try to catch a HTML element from the page we are waiting for
    'In this way the optimal break is achieved
    'To prevent an endless loop we insert a timeout
    'As the period of time for the timeout you can set the time in seconds you otherwise would use for Aplication.Wait()
    'In most cases this time will never reached
    timeoutStart = Timer
    Do
      'Do the trick by switching off error handling
      On Error Resume Next
      'Try to catch the table with the needed data
      Set nodeDataTable = ie.document.getElementById("example3")
      'Switch back on error handling
      On Error GoTo 0
    'Try again till the table could be catched or till timeout
    Loop While nodeDataTable Is Nothing Or Timer - timeoutStart > 15 'Timeout in seconds
    
    If Not nodeDataTable Is Nothing Then
      'Read data from all rows the whole table:
      'To make this possible, before accessing the table, we manipulate the dropdown responsible for setting the number of rows displayed.
      'If we manually set the number of rows to e.g. 50, this amount of rows will be displayed immediately. This means that there is no
      'further access to the server. All data is already contained in the document. It cannot be seen in the HTML code and there is no JSON.
      'Therefore, I assume that the data is stored in a JavaScript variable.
      '
      'For security reasons, JavaScript variables cannot be accessed from outside. But we have the "Dropdown" interface. If we had an entry
      'showing the maximum number of search hits or more, we would be able to display all rows at once.
      '
      'Attention:
      'With most internet pages, setting the records to be displayed higher only works in the dropdown. But the entry itself has no effect.
      '
      'With this website it works:
      'We change the entry for 100 search hits to be displayed to 10000. If more search hits are needed, this number can simply be increased.
      'Then we select the manipulated entry and read the whole table into the Excel sheet.
      '
      'Let's manipulate the 100 value of the dropdown to 10000
      'Here we don't need to switch off error handling, because we know the right page was loaded
      'Get the right dropdown
      Set nodeDropdown = ie.document.getElementById("example3_length").getElementsByTagName("select")(0)
      'Now select the entry to manipulate
      nodeDropdown.selectedIndex = 3
      'Manipulate it to 10000 (The value. Not the entry to display)
      nodeDropdown.getElementsByTagName("option")(3).Value = 10000
      'To make the entry work we must trigger the change event of the dropdown
      Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, nodeDropdown, "change")
      'Now we need a short periot of time to generate the whole table
      'Since we don't know the HTML code of the last row of the HTML table to use the loop trick, we wait flatly a second
      'That is the price for "immediately", without any knowlage
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
      'At this point we have the complete table
      'So we can read the data from all rows
      Set nodeAllDataRows = nodeDataTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
      For Each nodeOneDataRow In nodeAllDataRows
        With nodeOneDataRow
          dataSheet.Range("L" & currRowDataSheet) = .getElementsByTagName("td")(3).innerText  'Meter Con.
          dataSheet.Range("M" & currRowDataSheet) = .getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText  'Consumption (kWh)
          dataSheet.Range("N" & currRowDataSheet) = .getElementsByTagName("td")(12).innerText 'Balance
          Set nodeDate = .getElementsByTagName("td")(11)
          If IsDate(nodeDate.innerText) Then
            dataSheet.Range("O" & currRowDataSheet) = CDate(nodeDate.innerText) 'Pay Date
          Else
            dataSheet.Range("O" & currRowDataSheet) = nodeDate.innerText 'Pay Date
          End If
          currRowDataSheet = currRowDataSheet + 1
        End With
      Next nodeOneDataRow
    Else
      'If there is no data table (e.g. because the customer number is wrong)
      'you should do a notice about that. I do it in the data sheet.
      'I think another place would be better. But I don't know your whole project
      dataSheet.Range("L" & currRowDataSheet) = "No data table"
    End If
    
    'Clean up
    'You must close the IE first since it is a third party application
    'If you first delete the VBA reference to it you can't reach the ie longer from the makro
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    'If you don't set nodeDataTable to Nothing here
    'you will get a 462 (Server not found) in the second loop run
    'The reason is the termination condition of the loop to wait for the data table
    'Without the following line nodeDataTable is never Nothing again after the first
    'loop run, but than the code try to enter data without an object and terminates
    'in the named error in .Range("L" & currRow) = nodeDataTable...
    Set nodeDataTable = Nothing
    
    'Select the last row in the dataSheet. You have an optical feedback while reading data then
    dataSheet.Range("L" & currRowDataSheet).Select
  Next currRowNumberSheet
End Sub
```

**This sub() to trigger HTML events:**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir..... Its working. but one question... I need just last month details of all consumers, not all details. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SayedAli Ok, this is then always just the first row from the table, right?  `Bill Month` contains exactly one row for each month in the history. Is it then the case that the data read out still  ends up in the same table as the customer numbers?

Comment: Thank you Sir.... I have done as I wish.. Now I want to same things in Python code.... Kindly help me to learn it.... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Dear Sir, Hope u r fine. Your provided code is fine in windows 7 but problem showing when I code run in Windows 10 pro. Its showing problem "Run time error-462. The remote server machine does not exists or unavailable.